# Adding fields, account registrations and editing profile

Tags: users

By default Drupal has a profile system in place that stores user name, password and email.

[Profile2](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2) extends this to allow specific roles upon account creation as well as more options for adding fields.

The problem is there are now two sections for adding fields, two tabs for editing account info, and no way to separate account editing into unique sections, or combine everything onto one edit page.

How can I have fields be on specific edit forms separated by how I feel they should be categorized.

**Example:**
On user page there is an *edit* tab in user menu. when clicked there is a sub menu that has inks to specific edit forms: 1. edit profile 2. security info (password, phone number)  3. photos and media 4. Address 5. personal info 6. social networks

Why I asked the question: I sat down to add fields to the users pages, such as first name, last name and zip code and was very confuse where I should create these fields and which edit form they should live, the profile2 edit form or the core edit form.

Answer (score 0):

This is part of Profile2's interface design; different profile types (created in admin/structure/profiles) are presented as separate submenus on the user edit page.

If you want to work with the constraints of its interface, you can create profile type for each group of fields that you feel should be edited separately. If you feel like a field should be part of the main user edit page, you can add it to the core user entity (admin/config/people/accounts/fields).

As far as combining profile2 forms into the user edit form, Profile2 does allow you to embed profiles into the registration form (via its *Show on all user account registration forms.* option) but not the edit form. For that, there is the [Account Profile](https://www.drupal.org/project/account_profile) module.

> Profile2 by default creates an additional tab for each new profile
>   assigned to a user. Alternatively the submodule "Profile2 pages"
>   provides a separated pages for viewing and editing profiles.